Unable to Install Slack Bot in new workspaces Using OAuth
I have created my first Slack bot that responds to every new message in channels. My bot is not in the Slack App Directory yet. When installed in the primary workspace (the one where the app was originally created), the bot responds to messages as expected. However, when trying to install the bot in new workspaces using OAuth, the app is not installed in the new workspaces despite following the OAuth process.
I followed these steps:

Visited the Slack OAuth Authentication Guide. https://api.slack.com/authentication/oauth-v2
Selected my app and filled in the required fields.
Clicked 'Add to Slack' to open the 'Permission to Access' page.
Choose another workspace and clicked 'Allow'.
Redirected successfully.
However, when I check the new workspace, the app is not installed.
What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it to ensure the bot installs correctly in new workspaces ??

